# why does the code loop past 122 in ASCII Binary

Tags: java, char

So I'm having trouble understanding why the given code doesn't work out as intended as expected, what I want to get is for it to output the letter change (the change value) so for example the letter "a" + change(has a value of 3) is going to produce "d", except when the letter "number" + the change are greater than the letter "z" which has a value of 122 then it will loop to a and then go from there . (I tried every possible way to fix it but it doesn't work out as expected) please help thanks :D (also here is the input yzdkvyzgtyrkdspkcstqdkxlvpckdstckslbopbkotokizekmbedpkqzbnpkdstckmikdbityrkcstqdckzypkldklkdtxpkzbkecpklkqzbkwzzkdzkozkdspkcstqdtyrkwplcpkgbtdpkmbedpkqzbnpklckdspkvpikqzbkdlcvkyexmpbkdgz)

```
package LabExperience;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabExperienceChiper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("enter the code");
        Scanner machine = new Scanner(System.in);
         String let = machine.next();
         String news = "";
         int find;
         int find2;
        for(int change = -1; change <= 1; change++)
        {
         for(int x = 0; x<let.length(); x++)
         {
             char num = let.charAt(x);
             if(num + change > 122)
             {
                 find = 'z'-num;///find how much to take away from the change
                 find2 = change-find;////this takes the value 0f change and subtracts what is taken and adds it to the value of 'a'
                num= (char) (num + find2);
                news = news+num;
             }
             else
             {
                 if(num + change <= 122)
                 {
                 num = (char) (num + change);
                 news = news + num;
             }
             }
         }
        System.out.println(news);
        news = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put your input, the actual output, and your expected output.

Comment: Also, this is not a [mre] because I cannot copy and paste it into my ide to check it out. You need a class, a main method, and the import statements. All this is is a code snippit.

Comment: Also: your indentation is a mess.

Comment: added the class, main method, and the import statements and stuff (I think)

Comment: You say the code "doesn't work out as intended as expected," but you don't give any information as to what you expected it to do or what it actually does.

Comment: basically it's supposed to show every possible letter shift. so the shift goes from a-z (except when the letter plus the change value is greater than the value of z it will loop to a and go from there)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what the problem was in line 32 (the find 2 section). I didn't subtract 2 which caused an additional adding for the binary number (so 97 would be 99).